# Appdelegate.m throwing errors

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to run my react-native project build on xcode but unfortunately it started throwing an error for the Appdelegate.m file.

The three errors being thrown are:

1. Duplicate declaration of method 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
2. Expected expression
3. Use of undeclared identifier 'center'

I tried deleting the appdelegate.m file to see if the build would refresh but unfortunately it's still throwing the error. Shown below is the problem code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ...
  // Define UNUserNotificationCenter
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;

  return YES;
}
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. The project was working all morning and seemed to have just recently gone AWOL.

Comment: Did you add `@import UserNotifications;` at te beginning of the file?

Comment: Hey, that was it, thanks for the help!